# How to read value from encrypted cookie?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a Login Controller which is setting a cookie if user check the remember me checkbox,
but I want to do if the user next time visit my site & cookie is not expired yet so I redirect him to products page.

Here's the Controller Action

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyData data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (data.UserName == "abc" && data.Password == "123")
            {
                if (data.RememberMe == true)
                {
                    var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, data.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2), data.RememberMe,"");
                    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid User Name & Password");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Index Action of Controller

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if(//logic which is i am asking about)
        {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: i am wondering, if some other user logged in & check the box remember me then, is the cookie name is same for this user too? how i figure out it is a different user

Comment: The name of the cookie should be the same, but the values associated with it will be different for each user.  I would recommend setting a breakpoint at the if statement, and while debugging, add a watch variable of "Request.Cookies" and take a look at what is in that object.  You'll get a better understanding of what to look for after that.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

is all you need. Decrypting and expiring authentication cookies is the responsibility of forms authentication.

Comment: i tried this thing, but even after the cookie is expired the user is redirecting to the products page rather than the log in page

Comment: have you set the slidingExpiration to false? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.slidingexpiration.aspx